# Spring - decide on profile based on database

Tags: java, spring, spring-profiles, database-driven

We use a `WebApplicationInitializer` to decide the relevant Spring profile based on local properties

We want to decide on spring profile based on database table (one central place)

The issue is that not all beans are initialized, can it be done in a straight way?

Is it a good approach or anti-pattern/wrong to load spring profile from database ?

- Note we already use `@Order(1)` in our classes

I found [old related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32518368/loading-spring-profiles-from-database) but without any solution

> In ApplicationContextInitializer I cannot use Spring beans because the application context is not yet fully initialized. Is low level access to the database my only option?

There's option to keep a cluster servers which will load database and then all servers will get profile using cluster, but it seems like a overhead

Comment: We have been using the spring-config-server , which loads the proeprties from the different files, based on the profile it gets from the database.

Comment: @procrastinator problem with this solution we need to maintain additional server which can be down and prevent loading all severs (one point of failure) or cluster which may seem as an overhead

Comment: The question is: *why* do you want to load a parameter that is given either as a system property (via `-Dspring.profiles.active`), program argument (via `--spring.profiles.active`) or an environment variable 99% of the time, from a database? Do you also load JVM settings from the database?

Comment: @user991710 to have values in only one reliable secure place

Comment: Would JVM settings also be loaded using this mechanism?

Comment: @user991710 no, it's not related to JVM

Comment: While I understand the principle behind it, at the very least DB connection parameters would not be in one single place - that's already a big one. Perhaps something like [Hashicorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) might be more suited for an auditable retrieval of these kinds of technical startup parameters, IMO. Otherwise, I don't see a good way to do this without "low" level DB-access using `Connection`s and `ResultSet`s. The standard is, of course, the Spring Cloud Config Server.